# Enable and disable conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, visualization

Is it possible to enable and disable, or overwrite automatic conditional formatting in Excel with a checkbox?

I figured out how to do that for custom conditional formatting, but for bars that are generated automatically, I'm not sure how to do that.

For instance something like that:

[image]

How can I make the formatting disappear when toggling the box? Specifically, that it looks like so after disabling:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot use vba or c# to achieve that, because sending Excel files with active macros is a security concern for a lot of people.

Is there still a way how to achieve that, eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Enable & Disable Conditional Formatting Using CheckBox

Well, ***yes*** certainly its achievable, please follow the steps,

[image: Enable__Disable_Conditional_Formatting_Using_CheckBox]

• First select the range from `B2:D6`

• From **Home Tab** --> Under **Styles Group** --> Click **Conditional Formatting**,

• Click **New**,

• From **New Formatting Rule** Dialog Box --> Select Rule Type --> **Format all cells based on their values**,

• Under **Edit the Rule Description** --> Select Format Style as **Data Bar**

• Choose formatting accordingly and Press **Ok** -> **Ok**

[image: NEW_FORMATTING_RULE]

• Next from **Developer Tab** --> **Controls** Menu --> Click **Insert** --> Click **Check Box** From **Form Controls**

• Place the Check Box in Cell `F2` as shown in image,

• Now select the **Check Box**, right click on it, click **Format Control** --> Cell Link --> `F2` --> Press **Ok**

• Next select the cell `F2` --> Press `CTRL 1` --> **Format Cells** Dialog Box opens --> Under **Number Tab** --> **Category** --> **Custom** --> Type --> `;;;`

```
;;;
```

This hides the `TRUE's & FALSE's` which is occurs while **checking** and **unchecking** the **Check Box**,

• Select again the range `B2:D6`

• Press `ALT` `H` + `L` + `N` --> **New Formatting Rule** Dialog Opens --> Select the Rule Type --> **Use A Formula To Determine Which Cells To Format**, & enter the below formula, in the edit the rule description

```
=$F$2=FALSE
```

• Make sure the formatting will be **No Fill** i.e. **No Color should be chosen from the Fill Tab**,

[image: FORMATTING]

• Press **Ok** --> **Ok**

• Finally the above rule needs to be set as **STOP IF TRUE**, as shown below & apply

[image: STOP_IF_TRUE]

• Press **Ok**,

• Images below shown after **Checking** & **Unchecking** the **Check Box**,

**Unchecked Check Box**

[image: UNCHECKED]

**Checked Check Box**

[image: CHECKED]

Please refer the .gif link as well, to ensure it works!

**[Enable and disable conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxL5t.jpg)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I didn't think knew about 'Stop if True' checkbox.

Comment: @maggTech Sir, your welcome & glad it worked for you, ah yes `Stop If True` checkbox is essential in some conditional formatting rules, which really makes the difference, like in your query!

Answer (score 1):

I already got an awesome answer, just want to add one thing:

It is possible to have a label set on the linked cell for the checkbox. Just hit `Ctrl` + `1` and type `;;;"Show Conditional Formatting"` in custom settings - this way you do not need an extra cell.

This is what it looks like:

[image]